# Why can't I access my database on a webpage?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, permissions, web-config

I am getting an error on my web project. I have an aspx website that has a page that I use to view a database of a personal vinyl record collection. I used visual studio 2013 Professional to create the entire site and database. It works perfectly fine when I run the project in the Chrome test browser, but when I publish it and run it on a legit web browser, I get the error below. I have tried googling the problem, yet turned up empty. Could anyone point me in the direction I need to go? Do I need to change the access or trust level in the web.config file? What exactly would I put in the config file?

link: http://gipetransmissions.com/DBWebPage.aspx

Config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>

    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\JWVinylDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>

      <customErrors mode="Off"/>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

ERROR:

> Server Error in '/' Application. Security Exception Description: The
>   application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the
>   security policy. To grant this application the required permission
>   please contact your system administrator or change the application's
>   trust level in the configuration file. Exception Details:
>   System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed. Source Error: [No
>   relevant source lines] Source File: App_Web_ahkwuo05.2.cs Line: 0
>   Stack Trace: [SecurityException: Request failed.]
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) +0
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(PermissionSet permSet,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +31 System.Security.PermissionSet.Demand()
>   +68 System.Data.LocalDBAPI.DemandLocalDBPermissions() +241 System.Data.LocalDBAPI.CreateLocalDBInstance(String instance) +32
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo,
>   SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
>   Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean
>   integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) +5308411
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean
>   withFailover) +145
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +262
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer
>   timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +307
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions) +434
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +225
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +37
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions) +321
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions) +67
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1052
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +167
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +143
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource1
>   retry) +83 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset,
>   DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String
>   srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +121
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32
>   startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command,
>   CommandBehavior behavior) +316
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String
>   srcTable) +86
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments) +1482
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +21
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +138
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +30
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +4
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +105
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls()
>   +75 System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +83 System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +6704 System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +245 System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +72 System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) +21
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +58
>   ASP.dbwebpage_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in
>   App_Web_ahkwuo05.2.cs:0
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +341 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69 Version Information: Microsoft
>   .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34249

Comment: Make sure the username that your application is using have the correct privileges to access the database. If after that your still having the same issue make sure the script is running on a server with network access to the DB server with the correct ports open.

Comment: Can you move your Database file (JWVinylDB.mdf) to a database server, and use the proper [connection string](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1409.how-to-create-a-sql-connection-string-for-an-application-udl-file.aspx) pointing to this  database on the Database server ?

Comment: As basically a beginner, could you give me some more info on how to verify the username, check the ports, etc?

Comment: Also, how would I go about moving it to a database server? It is a very small and simple database, is that necesary to access the db on a webpage?

Comment: @AmishJohn81 Your connection is incorrect. Please ask your developer about correct connection string that you need to use. You still use localDB and this is for your localhost. If you host it on online server, you need to use the connection string that provided by your hoster.

Comment: @DouglasThomas I am my developer haha, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: @@AmishJohn81 I'm sorry, I mean you need to contact your hosting provider, ask them about the correct connection string that you need to use. Good luck. I believe you can solve it. :)

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same issue but adding the global file content which is displayed on the link page.

https://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/scripts-and-programming-languages-c85099/aspnet-c39624/explanation-of-security-exception-error-a611691.html